# Visual Studio 2015: Debugger won't step over

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to coding and this is my first time debugging (trying to learn).  When I run my project, it will stop on my first Breakpoint, Line 14.  I hit Step Over and it will go to Line 15 (see screenshot).

When I hit Step Over again, it builds the project and opens up in my browser and doesn't give me a chance to step into Line 21, the Step Over buttons are grayed out.

My expectation is that when I click Step Over, it will go to the next line in the code.  Am I misunderstanding how the step over and break points work?

[image]

Thank you.

After researching the answers given, the following link will provide more information to those interested in learning more about debugging.

[Getting Started with the Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt243867.aspx/)

Comment: You're at the end of `Page_Load`. Click the `okButton` to look at stepping into line 21 although the criteria of the `if` will have to be met.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior you're experiencing is both normal and correct.

You've set a break point on Line 14, which is part of the `Page_Load` event. This will trigger almost immediately -- before you see the browser window appear, if I'm not mistaken. Maybe it'll trigger immediately after the window opens, I forget exactly. Either way, if you click Step Over, it is supposed to go to Line 15. Even though the braces don't *do* anything, they do get 'executed'. By clicking Step Over a second time -- after the brace gets execute, you're effectively telling the debugger "OK, we've finished looking at `Page_Load`, go do whatever it is you're supposed to do next" -- and in this case, that's actually running your application in the browser.

Your second break point is in a completely separate method (event) titled `okButton_Click`. This will **only** fire when you click the `okButton` on your page. If your `Page_Load` included a call to `okButton_Click`, then you could use `Step Over` and it would eventually trigger the breakpoint on Line 21.

More information on exactly what the debugger buttons do can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251651.aspx) (see my edit below for a better link).

Kudos to you for learning / posting a question about the debugger. It is the most powerful tool a developer has, and many problems can easily be solved by yourself if you know how to use it.

**EDIT** This is a better link than the one above: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx

I didn't realize my first link was for VB scripts in Office products; but it essentially behaves the same.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description and the encouragement @sab669.  I'm thankful to all of the professionals helping newbies along, what a great community.

Comment: @JM1 So long as you show that an attempt was made, this site can be wonderfully helpful, yea. There are lots of questions that get posted all the time here with very simple logical errors that could easily be picked up on setting Break Points and using the [Watch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290869(v=vs.71).aspx) window and [Immediate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx) window. The former just lets you more easily keep track of a specific variable at all times so you can see exactly what  value it has, and Immediate lets you execute almost any statement.

Comment: In thinking about what you said in both comments, using the Debugger, the Watch, and the Immediate windows will take me through every step of the execution, and will show me what the values are, which will let me know if it's executing as intended.  I now see why you say it's the most powerful tool.  I can diagnose most things myself it seems using these tools, so it looks like I need to spend time learning Debugging at a deep level so it will save me tons of hours in the years ahead.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you are debugging in "Release" mode. Try changing the mode to "Debug" and re-run the application.

EDIT : Line 21 is the OK Button Click Event Handler. It will be Hit once you click OK on your web page/UI

Comment: Yes I missed it. When I read it first time there was a confusion. But did not remove it because it might help to know about the configurations to the newbies.

Comment: Thanks @Mit, It did make me double check, and it is in Debug mode, but I had not noticed there was such a configuration, so thank you for the comment.

Comment: Stupid question but why would "Release Mode" even matter? I just loaded up a console application, set a breakpoint, and built in release mode and it still triggers and behaves normally. I thought Release Mode just includes some optimizations and things like that?

Comment: There are many configs which affect Release and Debug Behavior. For e.g. Advanced Build Settings(Debug Info), DEFINE Debug Constant, Optimize code checkbox etc... in the Project Properties. Setting the values of these properties will define whether your breakpoints will be hit or not